# Certificate Warning, Is it important? What to do?

Tags: 14.04, certificates

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. The other day I  run:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

and on the last command - after some normal messages I got the following warning on my terminal:

```
Processing triggers for ca-certificates (20160104ubuntu0.14.04.1) ...
Updating certificates in /etc/ssl/certs... WARNING: Skipping duplicate certificate Go_Daddy_Class_2_CA.pem
WARNING: Skipping duplicate certificate Go_Daddy_Class_2_CA.pem
19 added, 19 removed; done.
Running hooks in /etc/ca-certificates/update.d....done.
```

What does it mean? Do I have to fix anything?

Answer (score 1):

Log it self saying you already have a SSL certificate there.

So even its downloaded due to its already there its not replacing existing one.

Goto location /etc/ssl/certs and verify its already there or not.

Comment: It's there but why did I get a warning? Could it be a fake? Do I have to delete it?